# If $f \circ g$ and $g \circ h$ are smooth, is $f \circ g \circ h$ smooth?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, smooth-functions

Given functions $f, g,$ and $h$ on some smooth manifold M such that $f \circ g$ and $g \circ h$ are $C^\infty$, must $f\circ g\circ h$  be $C^\infty$?

I can't imagine this is true, but I'm having trouble coming up with a counterexample. I've also had no luck in coming up with a proof, but I haven't been focusing on it for too long.

Comment: Does "smooth" mean $C^\infty$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, $C^\infty$ and smooth are synonymous here.

Comment: Aren't composites of $C^\infty$ functions always $C^\infty$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, but $f, g,$ and $h$ aren't necessarily smooth.

Comment: "Given $C^\infty$ functions $f$, $g$, and $h$"??

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Sorry, I mistyped the body of the question; yikes! I just edited it.

Comment: How about taking $f=g=h$ to be a non-smooth involution?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, I think that'll do it. You can post that as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown that answer works if such a function exists. Does one exist? Edit: on second thought, it seems fairly obvious that such a function should exist.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Yes, take $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that on the irrationals $f(x)=x$ and on the rationals $f(x)=-x$. Then $f$ isn't even continuous, but $f(f(x))=x$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Lord Shark the Unknown suggested, pick 
$$f=g=h= \left\{ \begin{array}{lc}
x & \mbox{ if } x \in \mathbb Q \\
-x & \mbox{ if } x \notin \mathbb Q \\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

More generally, pick any non-smooth bijection $f$ and set $g=f^{-1}$ and $h=f$.